# Change Rating using image from JSON

Tags: c#, json, image, gridview, uwp

I have a JSON like this:
[image: JSON]

I want to show the "rating" of data in gridview using the image below:

[image: rating null]

[image: rating full]

For example, the rating value is 5, it will be displayed as follows:

[image: rating 5]

and if the rating is 3, it will be displayed as follows:

[image: rating 3]

and if the rating is 0, it will be displayed as follows:

[image: rating 0]

code:

```
    try
                            {
                                loading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                                string urlPath1 = "http://.../results.json?module=listing&page=1&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f";
                                var httpClient1 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                                var values1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                                {

                                };
                                HttpResponseMessage response1 = await httpClient1.GetAsync(urlPath1);
                                response1.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                                if (!response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                                    RequestException();
                                }
                                string jsonText1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                JsonObject jsonObject1 = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText1);
                                JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject1["data"].GetArray();

                                foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
                                {
                                    JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();
string title = groupObject2["title"].GetString();
    double rating = groupObject2["rating"].GetNumber();


                                    ListingClass file1 = new ListingClass();
                                    file.Title = title;
                                    file1.Rating = Convert.ToInt32(rating);

                                    listingDatasource.Add(file1);
                                }
                                itemGridView.ItemsSource = listingDatasource;
                                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                            }

                            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                            {
                                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                                RequestException();
                            }
```

How do you show the rating using the picture?

Note:
The maximum value of the rating is 5

Comment: Do you have 5 unique images for the ratings or one sprite image?

Comment: @Sameer Yes, I use the picture above. For the rating value of 1 using a full color image of a star, while the rating is 0 using images of stars just border alone.

Comment: @fnostro I want to change the rating on json value using the above image.

Comment: @Rose - my mistake, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should be able to use the third-party control, such as [the UWP-Composition-Rating-Control](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-Composition-Rating-Control).

W should be able to set the your images to the FilledImage and EmptyImage property of the `Rating` control. Then we can bind the number of the Rating in ListingClass class to the Value of the `Rating` control.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView  Name="itemGridView">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                    <controls:Rating x:Name="Devils"
                     Value="{Binding Rating}"
                     Maximum="5"
                     ItemHeight="60"
                     ItemPadding="24"
                     StepFrequency="1"
                     EmptyImage="ms-appx:///Assets/empty.png"
                     FilledImage="ms-appx:///Assets/filled.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried clicking on the "the UWP-Composition-Rating-Control", but when clicked will link to these questions.

Comment: After I install XamlBrewer.Uwp.Rating nugget, my project can not be started because many conflict at the .dll

Comment: @Rose Please try to set the  "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" to "5.2.2" of the dependencies in project.json.